# Open ssh tunnel in Ant in and keep it open (but continue on to other tasks)

Tags: ssh, ant, build

I tried opening an ssh tunnel in ant, but it appears to close immediately and requires a task to run under it. How can I open a tunnel on a port and keep it open but not hang up the rest of the tasks while it sits open?

I tried:

```
<target name="tunnel">
    <sshsession host="${ssh.host}" username="${username}" keyfile="${keyfile}" localtunnels="${port}:localhost:${port}">
        <sequential />
    </sshsession>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. You can't use `sshsession` but instead have to use `exec`.

```
<exec spawn="true" executable="ssh">
    <arg value="-t" />
    <arg value="-t" />
    <arg value="-L" />
    <arg value="4003:localhost:4003" />
    <arg value="username@server" />
</exec>
```

**Note: The double `-t` is not an error. You need two of those or it won't work**

This starts it in the background. To shut it down, you need to find the pid, which you can do with a grep: `ps aux | grep 4003 | grep -v grep | awl '{print $2}'` and then kill it